# char is getting printed instead of integer in python

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm a newbie in python programming. As the title suggests char is getting printed instead of integer for the following code snippet. Thanks.

```
    nl=[]
    inp=raw_input()
    if inp.isdigit():
      list=inp.split()
      for s in list:
        nl.append(int(s))
    print nl
```

For example if I give an input as 1 2 3 the output obtained is ['1','2','3'] but the expected output is [1,2,3]. I want to print the answer in a list form.

Comment: What does this mean? What output are you seeing, and what are you expecting? There is no "char" data type in Python, in any case.

Comment: works for me, `nl` is a list of integers. If you want to print each index of nl, use `for i in nl: print i` instead of print nl

Comment: I don't understand: if the input is `'1 2 3'`, `nl` should be `[]` as `'1 2 3'` is not a digit...

Comment: -7! What on other has this guy done to the community :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nl = [int(n) for n in raw_input().split(' ') if n.isdigit()]
print nl
```

You have to split the input before to use `str.isdigit()` because `'1 2 3'` is not a digit.

Warning: if the numbers can be floating point numbers, you should use a regex instead of `str.isdigit()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understood that '1 2 3' is not a digit.

Comment: @ManojSiddu You're welcome. If it solved your problem, please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Being a novice myself, I can somewhat understand your situation.
So lets solve all the issues here:

1. `inp` will take a string from the user. Ex: "12345", "12 45" etc.
2. `inp.isdigit()` checks whether the string `inp` is composed of digits or not. Mind you, we are strictly speaking about digits (no other special characters).
   Ex: `"12345".isdigit()` returns `True` while `"12 45"`.isdigit() returns `False`.
3. `inp.split()` will return a list of words (or items) separated by a white space. Since, `isdigit()` and `split()` are contradicting each other, you are not getting a correct answer for "12 45" (or anything like this).

Hope you get my point.

**Tip** : Don't use `list` are a variable name. The code may work fine but it is not conventional.

Answer (score 1):

I like the list comprehension above but here's the same thing (without the use of isdigit) using a for loop-

```
nl = []
inp = raw_input()
lst = inp.split(' ')
for s in lst:
    nl.append(int(s))

print nl
```

A couple of quick points. Spaces before and after the equal sign (=) improves readability. You probably should avoid using list as a variable name since list is a built-in function. raw_input returns a string so "if inp.isdigit()" will always return false in your code.